Could not load controller 'joint_states_controller'
I am trying to implement a simple joint position and state controller on my robot, but i keep running into this error, I have reviewed similar questions and answers, but none suit my error, below i have attache the relevant sections of my Code;
URDF:
  <joint
    name="fork_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <calibration rising="0.0"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    <limit effort="30" velocity="1.0" lower="-0.8" upper="0.8" />
    <safety_controller k_velocity="10" k_position="15" soft_lower_limit="-2.0" soft_upper_limit="0.5" />
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 0.12"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="fork_link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />

  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="fork_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>

    <actuator name="motor1">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  </joint>

<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/trialtest1_bot</robotNamespace>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>

.YAML File:
body_joint_controller:
  joint_states_controller:
      type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
      publish_rate: 25
  
  body_trajectory_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: fork_joint
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}

Launch File:
<launch>
<rosparam file = "$(find trialtest1_bot)/config/body_joint_controller.yaml" command="load"/>

<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" ns="/trialtest1_bot" 
                args="joint_states_controller body_trajectory_controller"/>
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/simple_model/joint_states" />
</launch>

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you
